# How to write audio files in spi flash memory(W25Q32FV)

Tags: audio, memory, spi, flash-memory

I'm a newbie in handling flash memory.I want to play music from audio files store in flash memory. I have audio files in mp3 format. And I have converted them in wav file. I would like to know that how to write in spi flash memory using arduino.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Flash memory can be connected by plenty of different hardware interfaces. Your question is quite unclear in this respect.

Comment: I'm using arduino uno with  W25Q32FV.